# Continuous inclusions Sobolev theorem, question

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

How do I see that if $f$, $g \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $s > n/2$, then $fg \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and$$\|fg\|_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)} \le C\|f\|_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)}\|g\|_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)},$$the constant $C$ depending only on $s$ and $n$?

Comment: maybe with the Leibniz rule, [Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) and  induction on $s$?

Comment: Looking up your own references is good exercise. Voting to close as not a research level question.